# Import module from parent directory python

Tags: python

Please don't delete this. this is so simple but I'm banging my head making this work for last two hours.

As displayed. I want to import python file module_dir into module_sub_dir.py, but its giving erros. all **init**.py are empty.[image]

```
from .. import module_dir
```

This doesn't work either as it gives erro

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you running python sub_dir/module_sub_dir.py?

Comment: Starting python 2.5 you can import from parent using three dots: `from ... import module_dir`

Comment: @mikicz
I have opened 'dir' folder (main/root folder) in VS code.

Comment: @PietroD'Antuono got error
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: If you have `dir` folder open, then you shall import directly from the current folder. Then it is: `from . import module_dir`. Also, the folder containing `module_dir.py` must contain an `__init__.py` as well to be "recognized" as a python package

Comment: @PietroD'Antuono
I did try that. same error. went through so many videos and stackover flow answers but can't figure out the issue. ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 1):

Add `sys.path.append("..")` to the very beginning then importlib will be able to reach the file in parent directories of CWD. But I recommend you not to use such ugly solution in your projects.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to avoid that, I see that people making it work without sys.path but for some reason this is not working for me.

Comment: Another way to do something similar would be to define the environment variable PYTHONPATH to point to dir

Answer (score 0):

Update as I have figured out the issue myslef.

So the issue is how VS Code runs .py file individually as oppose to running entire package like Pycharm. It works in Pycharm. To make it work in VS Code sys.import.path('..') works.